# Calculating Moment of Inertia of a cone spinning around it's own axis

Tags: moment-of-inertia

I was having trouble calculating the moment of inertia of the cone, so I decided to search for other people's resolutions and found one that started this way:

[image]

Why is there a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$? Shouldn't the moment of inertia be $dI=r^2dm$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment of inertia of disk of radius $R$ is

$$ I_{\rm disk} = \frac{m}{2} R^2 $$

This is where the $\frac{r^2}{2}$ terms comes from.

The MMOI of a cone is the summation of individual disks, each with radius $r = \frac{R}{h} z$.

Start from the volume (to get the density) as

$$ V = \int_0^h \pi r^2 \,{\rm d} z = \int_0^h \pi \left( \frac{R}{h} z \right)^2 \,{\rm d} z = \frac{\pi}{3} h R^2 \;\;\;\checkmark $$

or specifically density is $\rho = \frac{m}{V}$ to be used below

Now formulate the MMOI

$$ I = \int_0^h \rho \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \right) \pi r^2 \,{\rm d} z = \int_0^h \frac{3 R^2 m z^4}{2 h^5}\,{\rm d}z = \frac{3}{10} m R^2 \;\;\; \checkmark $$

---

The above assumes you know the MMOI of a disk. If you want to derive the formula from a fundamental level using $I = \int r^2 {\rm d}m$ then use the following

1. Do the volume integral to get the density

   $$ \begin{aligned}{\rm d}V & =r\,{\rm d}r{\rm d}\theta{\rm d}z\\
   V & =\int_{0}^{h}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{R}{h}z}r\,{\rm d}r{\rm d}\theta{\rm d}z\\
    & =\int_{0}^{h}\tfrac{\pi\,R^{2}\,z^{2}}{h^{2}}{\rm d}z=\tfrac{1}{3}\pi R^{2}h
   \end{aligned} $$
2. Do the mmoi integral

   $$ \begin{aligned}{\rm d}I & = r^2 {\rm d}m = \rho r^{2}{\rm d}V\\
   I & =\int_{0}^{h}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{R}{h}z}(\rho\,r^{2})\,r\,{\rm d}r{\rm d}\theta{\rm d}z\\
    & =\tfrac{m}{V}\int_{0}^{h}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{R}{h}z}r^{3}\,{\rm d}r{\rm d}\theta{\rm d}z\\
    & =\frac{m}{\tfrac{1}{3}\pi R^{2}h}\frac{\pi\,R^{4}h}{10}=\tfrac{3}{10}m\,R^{2}
   \end{aligned} $$

Comment: But shouldn't it be possible to reach that expression starting with $I = \int_0^h r^2 dm$?

Comment: @PedroNogueira No. You can't start from a starting point that differs by a factor of two and end up in the same place... Maybe you are asking if there is some way to start from $\int d^3r r^2 dm$ and use a different expression for $dm$. Yes, you could do that, but you would just be re-deriving the expression for the moment of inertia of a disk and then you would be back to the starting point of this answer.

Comment: @PedroNogueira - yes you can. see update on post.

Comment: @hft - you can by using a full triple integral and note that $\int r {\rm d}r = \tfrac{1}{2} r^2$